# Sql table transposed in table HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

I have this table:

```
+----+---------+------+----------+
| ID | ID_USER | NOTE | QUESTION |
+----+---------+------+----------+
|  1 |    12   |   3  |     1    |
|  2 |    31   |   2  |     1    |
|  3 |    12   |   9  |     1    |
|  4 |    31   |   8  |     2    |
|  5 |    12   |  10  |     2    |
|  6 |    31   |   3  |     2    |
|  7 |    14   |   4  |     3    |
+----+---------+------+----------+
```

How can I extract the values in sql table and expose them in an HTML table as the one below?

```
+----------+----+----+----+
| QUESTION | 12 | 31 | 14 |
+----------+----+----+----+
|     1    |  6 |  2 |  0 |
|     2    |  2 |5.5 |  0 |
|     3    |  0 |  0 |  3 |
+----------+----+----+----+
```

The values 6, 5.5, 3 are averages.
Work with php-mysqli.

I have started code, but i don't know how to convert row in column. My code generate two columns and rows equal with the number of ID-s. I need to generate two rows and columns equal with the number of ID-s.

```html
<?php
 include 'bd_cnx.php';
 $sql = "SELECT
           id_user,
           question,
           AVG(note) AS medium_note
         FROM notes
         GROUP BY id_user, question";

 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo '<tr><th>QUESTION</th>
               <th>'. $row['id_user'] .'</th></tr>';
     echo '<tr><td>'. $row['question'] .'</td><td>' . $row['medium_note'] . '</td></tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good place for code writing requests or broad "how do I do complex thing X" type questions. You may want to look into the basics of doing this, and return when you have specific questions

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post.

Comment: what you are looking for are pivot table. Try to have a look on SO and google and you will find plenty of information :)